# Getting html tags in php when uploading youtube embedded code

Tags: javascript, php, css

I am uploading youtube embedded code in database when i getting it's not showing video and showing html tags like this here's my code

```
$gettingmessageform=$t["message1"];
echo '<span><a href="javascript:void(0)"  onclick="Alert.render(\''.$gettingmessageform.'\')" "/>'.$t["username1"].'</a></span></br>Age:'.$t["age1"].'</br>'.$t["location1"].'</br>';
```

it's showing like this when i retrieving the code from database

```
')" "/>talent
```

Regards
Aashish

Comment: you should be thankful then. Keep uploading script  and you are wide open to attack

Comment: Look into database injection.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting

Comment: Please read up on SQL and XSS injection. You've basically proven that your application is vulnerable and wide open to attack. http://www.acunetix.com/websitesecurity/sql-injection/

Answer (score 0):

if you don't know about injection please learn. but before that you can save http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=juLRqSV45vo link or just juLRqSV45vo into your database,
then echo like this,

```
echo ' <iframe width="420" height="315" src="'.$urlFromDatabase.'" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>';
```

or for second saving options;

```
echo ' <iframe width="420" height="315" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/'.$embed.'" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>';
```